# Define a collection inside XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, markup-extensions

I want to create a Binding to a collection of strings defined inside XAML.

In WPF I could create an `ArrayList` as a resource with a key, ready to be used as the source of a Binding (using a StaticResource).

Is this possible in Xamarin Forms?

**EDIT:** I've tried with this XAML with the solution proposed by @Stephane Delcroix, but I'm getting an Unhandled Exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             x:Class="ReferenceApp.Views.GamesPage"
             Title="Games">


    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="array">
            <x:String>Hello</x:String>
            <x:String>World</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid />

</ContentPage>
```

However, the exception is not thrown if I remove the `<x:Array >... </x:Array>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What control and which property of the control are you trying to bind your list to? I know how to do it for `Picker.Items` but not sure about a `ListView.ItemSource` for example.

Comment: I would like to use the ItemsSource of a ListView

Comment: You might still be able to work off the `Picker` example [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24023/adding-a-picker-in-xaml).

Answer (score 10):

I see that you are using the **XF standard markup extensions**. Your mistake seems to be in `Type="{x:Type sys:String}"`, instead of **sys:String** you should write **x:String** which appears in the common **xmlns:x**

In this sample I fill a listview with strings

```
<ListView Margin="10">
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Hello</x:String>
            <x:String>World</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>            
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built-in `x:Array`

```xml
<x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="array">
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
    <x:String>World</x:String>
</x:Array>
```

with `sys` defined as `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

or any collection you like, e.g. `List`

```xml
<scg:List x:TypeArguments="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="genericList">
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
    <x:String>World</x:String>
</scg:List>
```

with `sys` defined as before, and `scg` being `xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: I've tried it, but in Android I'm getting an Unhandled Exception. Please, see my edit in the OP.

Comment: `String` is not defined in `System.Runtime` but in `mscorlib` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Also, modifying questions usually makes the answer irrelevant, so please avoid doing that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any other way to paste the XAML.

Comment: BTW, I've modified the XAML with the xmlns poiting to mscorlib and it happens the same: I get an Unhandled Exception.

Comment: this snippet was copy pasted from my unit tests of the XF xaml parser, so it should work. if it does not, please report a bug

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the updated question.

`<x:string>` only supports constant values. You can address this issue with a [Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/)

Its functionality is trivial: it returns its parameter.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace YOURAPP.Extensions
{
    public class StringExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this in a view:

1. Add `xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:YOURAPP.Extensions"` to the root element
2. `<ext:StringExtension Value="{anything here}" />` where you would otherwise want `<x:string>`

Note that this causes an `Add` to be called to the `IEnumerable`. For custom controls you would need initialization (to avoid a `NullReferenceException`) and and `ObservableCollection` to make sure that the view is updated on adding.